# Spring security 3 + JCIFS ntlm

Tags: spring-security, ntlm, jcifs

Can they work together? 
Some project sample would be great.

I have a web-app on Spring3. And i need to implement NTLM. Spring stopped NTLM support in 3rd version. Is there any possibilities to implement it?

Looking for a sample project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can be used together.  Essentially what you want to do is hook into the SPNEGO protocol and detect when you receive an NTLM packet from the client.  A good description of the protocol can be found here:

http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html

http://blogs.technet.com/b/tristank/archive/2006/08/02/negotiate-this.aspx

Another great resource for NTLM is this:

http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html

But you asked for a sample so here goes.  To detect an NTLM packet you need to base64 
decode the packet and inspect for a starting string:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if ((header != null) && header.startsWith("Negotiate ")) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Received Negotiate Header for request " + request.getRequestURL() + ": " + header);
        }
        byte[] base64Token = header.substring(10).getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] decodedToken = Base64.decode(base64Token);

    if (isNTLMMessage(decodedToken)) {
        authenticationRequest = new NTLMServiceRequestToken(decodedToken);
    }

...
}

public static boolean isNTLMMessage(byte[] token) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (token[i] != NTLMSSP_SIGNATURE[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static final byte[] NTLMSSP_SIGNATURE = new byte[]{
        (byte) 'N', (byte) 'T', (byte) 'L', (byte) 'M',
        (byte) 'S', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'P', (byte) 0
};
```

You'll need to make an authentication provider that can handle that type of authenticationRequest:

```
import jcifs.Config;
import jcifs.UniAddress;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.NtlmMessage;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type1Message;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type2Message;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type3Message;
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbSession;
import jcifs.util.Base64;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsChecker;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * User: gcermak
 * Date: 3/15/11
 * <p/>
 */
public class ActiveDirectoryNTLMAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider, InitializingBean {
    protected String defaultDomain;
    protected String domainController;

    protected UserDetailsChecker userDetailsChecker = new AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker();

    public ActiveDirectoryNTLMAuthenticationProvider(){
        Config.setProperty( "jcifs.smb.client.soTimeout", "1800000" );
        Config.setProperty( "jcifs.netbios.cachePolicy", "1200" );
        Config.setProperty( "jcifs.smb.lmCompatibility", "0" );
        Config.setProperty( "jcifs.smb.client.useExtendedSecurity", "false" );
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        NTLMServiceRequestToken auth = (NTLMServiceRequestToken) authentication;
        byte[] token = auth.getToken();

        String name = null;
        String password = null;

        NtlmMessage message = constructNTLMMessage(token);

        if (message instanceof Type1Message) {
            Type2Message type2msg = null;
            try {
                type2msg = new Type2Message(new Type1Message(token), getChallenge(), null);
                throw new NtlmType2MessageException(Base64.encode(type2msg.toByteArray()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new NtlmAuthenticationFailure(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (message instanceof Type3Message) {
            final Type3Message type3msg;
            try {
                type3msg = new Type3Message(token);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new NtlmAuthenticationFailure(e.getMessage());
            }
            final byte[] lmResponse = (type3msg.getLMResponse() != null) ? type3msg.getLMResponse() : new byte[0];
            final byte[] ntResponse = (type3msg.getNTResponse() != null) ? type3msg.getNTResponse() : new byte[0];

            NtlmPasswordAuthentication ntlmPasswordAuthentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(type3msg.getDomain(), type3msg.getUser(), getChallenge(), lmResponse, ntResponse);

            String username = ntlmPasswordAuthentication.getUsername();
            String domain = ntlmPasswordAuthentication.getDomain();
            String workstation = type3msg.getWorkstation();

            name = ntlmPasswordAuthentication.getName();
            password = ntlmPasswordAuthentication.getPassword();
        }

        // do custom logic here to find the user ... 
        userDetailsChecker.check(user);

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, user.getAuthorities());
    }

    // The Client will only ever send a Type1 or Type3 message ... try 'em both
    protected static NtlmMessage constructNTLMMessage(byte[] token) {
        NtlmMessage message = null;
        try {
            message = new Type1Message(token);
            return message;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if ("Not an NTLMSSP message.".equals(e.getMessage())) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        try {
            message = new Type3Message(token);
            return message;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if ("Not an NTLMSSP message.".equals(e.getMessage())) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return message;
    }

    protected byte[] getChallenge() {
        UniAddress dcAddress = null;
        try {
            dcAddress = UniAddress.getByName(domainController, true);
            return SmbSession.getChallenge(dcAddress);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new NtlmAuthenticationFailure(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> auth) {
        return NTLMServiceRequestToken.class.isAssignableFrom(auth);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        // do nothing
    }

    public void setSmbClientUsername(String smbClientUsername) {
        Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.username", smbClientUsername);
    }

    public void setSmbClientPassword(String smbClientPassword) {
        Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.password", smbClientPassword);
    }

    public void setDefaultDomain(String defaultDomain) {
        this.defaultDomain = defaultDomain;
        Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.domain", defaultDomain);
    }

    /**
     * 0: Nothing
     * 1: Critical [default]
     * 2: Basic info. (Can be logged under load)
     * 3: Detailed info. (Highest recommended level for production use)
     * 4: Individual smb messages
     * 6: Hex dumps
     * @param logLevel  the desired logging level
     */
    public void setDebugLevel(int logLevel) throws Exception {
        switch(logLevel) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 6:
                Config.setProperty("jcifs.util.loglevel", Integer.toString(logLevel));
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid Log Level specified");
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param winsList a comma separates list of wins addresses (ex. 10.169.10.77,10.169.10.66)
     */
    public void setNetBiosWins(String winsList) {
        Config.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.wins", winsList);
    }

    public void setDomainController(String domainController) {
        this.domainController = domainController;
    }
}
```

And finally you need to tie it all together in your spring_security.xml file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <form-login login-page="/auth/login"
                    login-processing-url="/auth/j_security_check"/>
        <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices"/>
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/auth/logoutMessage" logout-url="/auth/logout"/>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/error/accessDenied"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUsernamePasswordUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
                <salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
            </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
        <authentication-provider ref="NTLMAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Lastly you need to know how to tie it all together.  The protocol as described in the first set of links shows that there are a couple round trips that you need to make between the client and server.  Thus in your filter you need a bit more logic:

```
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type1Message;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type2Message;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.codec.Base64;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceRequestToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * User: gcermak
 * Date: 12/5/11
 */
public class SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if ((header != null) && header.startsWith("Negotiate ")) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Received Negotiate Header for request " + request.getRequestURL() + ": " + header);
            }
            byte[] base64Token = header.substring(10).getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] decodedToken = Base64.decode(base64Token);

            // older versions of ie will sometimes do this
            // logic cribbed from jcifs filter implementation jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter
            if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
                if (decodedToken[8] == 1) {
                    logger.debug("NTLM Authorization header contains type-1 message. Sending fake response just to pass this stage...");
                    Type1Message type1 = new Type1Message(decodedToken);
                    // respond with a type 2 message, where the challenge is null since we don't
                    // care about the server response (type-3 message) since we're already authenticated
                    // (This is just a by-pass - see method javadoc)
                    Type2Message type2 = new Type2Message(type1, new byte[8], null);
                    String msg = jcifs.util.Base64.encode(type2.toByteArray());
                    response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Negotiate " + msg);
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    response.setContentLength(0);
                    response.flushBuffer();
                    return;
                }
            }

            Authentication authenticationRequest = null;
            if (isNTLMMessage(decodedToken)) {
                authenticationRequest = new NTLMServiceRequestToken(decodedToken);
            } 

            Authentication authentication;
            try {
                authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationRequest);
            } catch (NtlmBaseException e) {
                // this happens during the normal course of action of an NTLM authentication
                // a type 2 message is the proper response to a type 1 message from the client
                // see: http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html
                response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", e.getMessage());
                response.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.setContentLength(0);
                response.flushBuffer();
                return;
            } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                // That shouldn't happen, as it is most likely a wrong configuration on the server side
                logger.warn("Negotiate Header was invalid: " + header, e);
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                if (failureHandler != null) {
                    failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, e);
                } else {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                    response.flushBuffer();
                }
                return;
            }
            if (successHandler != null) {
                successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            }
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    public void setSuccessHandler(AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler) {
        this.successHandler = successHandler;
    }

    public void setFailureHandler(AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
        this.failureHandler = failureHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws ServletException {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
        Assert.notNull(this.authenticationManager, "authenticationManager must be specified");
    }
}
```

You'll see that in the exception we use "Negotiate" rather than NTLM:

```
/**
 * User: gcermak
 * Date: 12/5/11
 */
public class NtlmType2MessageException extends NtlmBaseException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NtlmType2MessageException(final String type2Msg) {
        super("Negotiate " + type2Msg);
    }
}
```

The spring filter (above) was largely patterned on jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter which you can find in the source for jcifs here:

http://jcifs.samba.org/

This isn't a whole, downloadable project as you requested but if there is interest from the community I could add this NTLM code to my github project:

http://git.springsource.org/~grantcermak/spring-security/activedirectory-se-security

Hope this helps!

Grant

Comment: Thanks. Already fixed IE with a doFilter method. But I will definetly try your spring+jscifs samples at a weekend.